# How to center a Div across all Monitors/Resolutions/Browsers?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have created my own light box, the problem is that it shows centered on my monitor but not on wider monitors or bigger resolutions.

What is the best way to center a div across all resolutions/monitors/browers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Centered horizontally, vertically or both? If you want both, [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20170317104010/http://www.sitecrafting.com/blog/to-center-div/) has worked for me in the past. Otherwise, the answer [sathish posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830942/how-to-center-a-div-across-all-monitors-resolutions-browsers/1830956#1830956) is good for horizontal only centering

Answer (score 5):

Try using this

Make parent div style as center and use `margin: 0 auto;` to the child div

```
#parentDiv{
text-align: center;
}

#main{
margin:0 auto;
width:755px;
text-align: left;
}
```

`<div id="parentDiv"><div id="main">Content</div></div>`

Comment: The old text-align hacks? Can't we abandon IE<=5.5 yet?

Answer (score 2):

`#center {position:absolute; width:400px; height:400px; left:50%; top:50%; margin:-200px /must be half of the height/ 0 0 -200px; /must be half of the width/}`

that will center the div horizontally and vertically. In relation to its first parent with the position:relative;

Comment: This is a horrible approach that leads to the off-left-with-no-scrollbars problem.

Answer (score 0):

if you know the width:

```
<div></div>

div {
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -50px; /* width / 2 */
  width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: This is a horrible approach that leads to the off-left-with-no-scrollbars problem.

Comment: what is that ? 

Never had problems with it :)

Answer (score 0):

well if you set everything to be centered using

```
*{margin:0 auto;}
```

it will center anything in your document unless told otherwise

or you can use a wrapper div

```
div#wrapper {margin:0 auto;}
```

if your using older browser you should use

```
div#wrapper {text-align:center;}
```

there is like 30 ways of doing it, kinda depends on what your doing...

these are the most easy ones

Answer (score 0):

Set a width on the div and then give it a centering class:

```
.center
{
margin:0 auto;
}
```

It will be centered in any browser.

Answer (score 0):

although all the answers above seem correct i did get stuck on this myself for a moment. Here is my simplified approach.

Let's say you have the code below and you want to center the content within the div 'storyline-container'.

```
<body>
    <div class="storyline-container">
        <script src=storyline.js type="text/javascript"></script>
    </div>
</body>
```

Simply writing the code below won't work because you also need to center align the parent div which in this case is the 'body'

```
.storyline-container 
{
    text-align: center;
}
```

Add the code below in your css file to solve your problem.

```
body{
    text-align: center;
}
```